# I am getting "**502 Bad Gateway**" error for my Laravel Vapor deployment

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, devops, laravel-vapor, vapor-cloud

I am getting "**502 Bad Gateway**" error for my Laravel Vapor deployment. I was able to successfully deploy the code in Vapor, but when I go to the link is gave or the domain that I had used during the deploymet it gives me "**502 Bad Gateway**" error.

I have used runtime as **"docker"** as I have to run a php8.2 application.
I have also tried to use runtime **Amazon Linux 2 8.2** but still the same error.

I have already tried to change the timeout to 5mins and check, but still the same issue.

When I checked the Logs Tab in Vapor it shows below log details:
**2023-09-21T11:46:36.063Z 8c113dcf-2ae9-476c-9503-456bc2e1cd86 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds**

Can someone please help me on this as it is happening on Production environment for one of my client.

I have already tried to change the timeout to 5mins and check, but still the same issue.

When I checked the Logs Tab in Vapor it shows below log details:
**2023-09-21T11:46:36.063Z 8c113dcf-2ae9-476c-9503-456bc2e1cd86 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds**

Comment: Where have you changed the default timeout to 5 min?

Comment: in vapor.yml file

Comment: Can i please see your config related to this timeout? Because this is related to timeout of API gateway which by default is 10s, and max is 30s.